# Using row template and column formatter

Tags: kendo-grid, knockout-kendo

How to have correctly formated data in columns when row template is used?

I'm creating a grid with knockout-kendo where I define columns and row template:

```
<div data-bind="kendoGrid: {
    data: Entries, 
    sortable: true, 
    selectable: true, 
    useKOTemplates: true,
    rowTemplate: 'rowTemplate',
    columns: [
        {
            title: 'Created on',
            field: 'Timestamp',
            format: '{0:d}'
        },
        {   
            title: 'The Mighty Value', 
            field: 'Value' 
        },
        {
            title: 'I.D.',
            field: 'Id'
        },
        {}
    ]}"></div>
```

If I do so my first column's display format will be lost because of custom template. How to overcome this issue?

JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/cXDcm/7/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are using a custom row template you are responsible to format your column values.

However you can you use the built in [`kendo.format` method](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/kendo#methods-format) also in your template to manually apply your formatting:

```
<td data-bind="text: kendo.format('{0:d}',Timestamp())"></td>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wufB8/).

Comment: what if the html is stored in a string that is returned by a column template function?  having a hard time with that..var ts = "<td data-bind=\"text: kendo.format('{0:d}',Timestamp())\"></td>"